# Issue while trying to read a text file in databricks using Local File API's rather than Spark API

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, sparkapi

I'm trying to read a small txt file which is added as a table to the default db on Databricks. While trying to read the file via Local File API, I get a `FileNotFoundError`, but I'm able to read the same file as *Spark RDD* using **SparkContext**.

Please find the code below:

```
with open("/FileStore/tables/boringwords.txt", "r") as f_read:
  for line in f_read:
    print(line)
```

This gives me the error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2618449717515592> in <module>
----> 1 with open("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/boringwords.txt", "r") as f_read:
      2   for line in f_read:
      3     print(line)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/boringwords.txt'
```

Where as, I have no problem reading the file using **SparkContext**:

```
boring_words = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/boringwords.txt")
set(i.strip() for i in boring_words.collect())
```

And as expected, I get the result for the above block of code:

```
Out[4]: {'mad',
 'mobile',
 'filename',
 'circle',
 'cookies',
 'immigration',
 'anticipated',
 'editorials',
 'review'}
```

I was also referring to the [DBFS documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#fuse&language-python) here to understand the Local File API's limitations but of no lead on the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the `open` function that works only with local files, and doesn't know anything about DBFS, or other file systems. To get this working, you need to use [DBFS local file API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis) and append the `/dbfs` prefix to file path: `/dbfs/FileStore/....`:

```py
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/boringwords.txt", "r") as f_read:
  for line in f_read:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can simply use the built-in csv method:

```
df = spark.read.csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/boringwords.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we can use `dbutils`

```
files = dbutils.fs.ls('/FileStore/tables/')
li = []
for fi in files: 
  print(fi.path)
```

Example ,

[image]